# @GeneratedValue not generating id value in entity class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

my entity class trying to implement for
stocks.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="stocks")
public Class Stocks
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "stock_id")
private Integer stocked;
}
```

this my rest API controller I wrote
stockcontroller.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("home/stocks")
public class HomeController {

@Autowired
private StockRepo stocks;



//POST: adds a new song to the repository
@PostMapping("/add")
public void addSong(@RequestBody(required = true) Stock stock) throws DuplicateItemException {
    if(stock.existsById(stock.stockId())) {
        throw new DuplicateItemException();  
    }
    stocks.save(song);
}
```

}

Comment: It will only be generated when it is persisted, so a new one doesn't have an id.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the generation strategy.

For example you can replace `@GeneratedValue` with:

```java
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

or

```java
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
```

or

```java
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
```

Of course, you have to put `@Transactional` on the method `addSong` to persist the entity.

Answer (score 0):

change @GeneratedValue to @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
or @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)